# How to find packages where table name is used more than twice

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g, database-administration

I've a task to list down package names for an owner where the same table names are used more than twice or 5 times in some cases.

I came up with following query, however dba_dependencies doesn't give the result I want.

```
select type,REFERENCED_NAME from dba_dependencies where REFERENCED_NAME in
 (select 
  REFERENCED_NAME
 from 
   dba_dependencies
 where 
    owner = 'SITTEST' and REFERENCED_TYPE='TABLE'
   and type='PACKAGE'
 group by REFERENCED_NAME having count(*)>5);
```

I tried using all_source and dba_source but no dice.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use ALL_SOURCE (DBA_SOURCE) instead of all dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An odd requirement!  You would have to search the source code of the packages since DBA_DEPENDENCIES will only contain a single row per dependency.

Something like this should do it (I have used USER% views for simplicity):

```
select t.table_name, p.object_name, count(*)
from user_tables t
cross join user_objects p
join user_source s on s.name = p.object_name
         and s.type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
         and upper(s.text) like '%' || upper(t.table_name) || '%'
where p.object_type = 'PACKAGE BODY'
group by t.table_name, p.object_name
having count(*) > 5;
```

But - that will count false positives since it is just looking for the text, which may not really be a usage.

Comment: yes this is something i have been trying by joining dba_dependencies and dba_source. But Yes! your query is more simpler. Also we may have to add upper() ? since I see some are in lower and some in upper case.

Comment: Exactly what I was attempting but I kept running into the false positives and trying to figure out how to eliminate them; to no avail.

Comment: @dicaprio, yes need upper() or lower() - now added above.